# diskpart: creating primary partion error

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, diskpart

I am trying to do clean install Windows 10 from a bootable flash drive, but when I try to make a partition I get this error:

> We couldn't create a new partition [Error 0x80070017].

<sup>[[image here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qq7i.jpg).</sup>

Then I followed these steps that should fix it:

- `select disk 0`
- `clean`
- `create partition primary`
- `active`
- `format fs=ntfs quick`
- `assign`

When I typed `create partition primary` I got this error:

> DiskPart has encountred an error: data error (cyclic redundancy check).

<sup>[[image here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOXCd.jpg)</sup>

I also got an error:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. 
>   This computer's hardware may not supporting to this disk. 
>   Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

<sup>[[image here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrAWK.jpg)</sup>

This is weird; it was running normally before.

Looks like I can't access my drive, Any ideas?

Comment: Bad boot sector?

Comment: Here's another clarification, https://imgur.com/a/ZE7k6eU, it says the computer hardware may not support booting to this disk, weird it was running normaly before

Comment: Why are you manually creating the partition?  The installation environment will do that for you.  Why are you installing an old (more than 3 year old) Windows Insider build of Windows 10.  Third error is caused by a mix match of legacy/UEFI and MBR vs GPT